# How to set up Azure monitoring on CloudMonix to grant least privilege?

Tags: monitoring, azure

Could someone provide some guidance on what the best way to set up Azure monitoring on CloudMonix such that I only grant the least amount of privilege needed to monitor specific resources?

One of the options is to upload a publish settings profile file, which seems convenient, but I feel as though I am "giving away the keys to the kingdom".

Is there a best practices way to set up this relationship and manage what can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Setup in CloudMonix depends on the resources you're trying to monitor.
Certain resources can only be monitored via Classic API (such as Classic VMs, Classic Storage, Cloud Services, Service Bus and WebApps).  Classic resources require a certificate to communicate with Azure API and this certificate enables access to everything in the Classic model.  This was one of the shortcomings of the classic models in Azure which is why ARM API was introduced with its role-based access.

When dealing with v2/ARM resources, such as v2 VMs, Storage, Backup, Stream Analytics, etc (Setup Wizard in CloudMonix clearly identifies which method supports which resources), you can provision CloudMonix via the Setup Wizard to create a "CloudMonix" user account with your Azure AD.  After Setup Wizard is over, you can remove certain permissions from CloudMonix user whereby limiting its reach.

Furthermore, depending on the resources you're monitoring with CloudMonix, they maybe monitored without talking to Azure API at all (such as SQL Azure, VMs, Service Bus, Storage, etc).  This may mean less functionality but still workable for monitoring and automating purposes.

HTH